# Swift: Realm How to filter Int contains number as String

Tags: swift, realm

I have a string input "searchText" and I need to check in realm filter if id(Int) is contains any number in "searchText"

```
let searchText = "118523"

let messages:Results<ChatMessage> = realm
    .objects(ChatMessage.self)
    .filter("body CONTAINS %@ OR id CONTAINS %@" , searchText, searchText)
    .sorted(byKeyPath: "timeStamp", ascending: true)
```

Comment: To clarify, you want to filter your realm objects for any of the numbers in the searchText string? So filter for object whole body or id contains "1" OR "8" OR "5"...?

Comment: Exactly yes....

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, given a set of characters, the OP wants to find any chat messages that have any of those characters in the id (or body). I am leaving body out as the pattern is the same for any field.

```
let searchText = "118523"
let charArray = Array(searchText) //casts each element to an Array of Characters

var predicateArray = [NSPredicate]()
for element in charArray {
    let searchChar = String(element) //cast each Character to a string 
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id CONTAINS %@", searchChar)
    predicateArray.append(predicate)
}

let predicates = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicateArray)

let results = realm.objects(ChatMessage.self).filter(predicates)
for msg in results {
    print(msg)
}
```

Explanation

First, the searchText is broken down to individual characters and stored in an array.

Then, using a loop, an NSPredicate is built using each character to see if the id contains that character. Note that we need to cast the Swift Character to a String to be used in the predicate. Each predicate is stored in an array of predicates.

Then those predicates are all joined together as OR's into an NSCompoundPredicate.

Lastly we filter realm ChatMessage objects for any id's that CONTAIN any of characters within each Predicate, which would be "1" or "1" or "8" etc.

This could be a bit more efficient if we used a Set instead of an Array which would only store unique values e.g. no point in filtering for "1" or "1" - just one "1" would be enough.